# Generate random samples from mixture distribution (continuous)

Tags: python, statistics

I have a set of variables A, B, C where C is the average between A and B.  I can manage to get data of C but A and B are missing.  If i have 5 samples, my data look like this.

```
A   B    C
?   ?   100
?   ?   150
?   ?   125
?   ?   115
?   ?   130
```

If I assume that A, B  and C follow normal distribution but I can know only the mean, max, and min for A and B.  Is there any possible way to generate samples from this settings using python?

Comment: This sounds like a logical puzzle more than anything. If my intuition is correct, i think you can do it as long as the values provided for the mean max and min have certain restrictions. You may not have solutions for arbitrary values.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't know the min and max of A and B? Only the mean for each event? But you do know the min and max of the 5 means (C). Do we assume A and B coming from the same normal distribution (equal mean and variance) or are they different?

Comment: The normal distribution is defined using only the `mean` and `standard deviation`. If one of these is missing, you can't map the values properly